# What could be the problem with codeigniter force_download()

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am using Codeigniter and want to achieve download functionality for my project, I am able to run the download functionality on my localhost, but while I try to deploy/integrate that same code on the server it shows `undefined function force_download();`

The code is running fine on localhost and all the similar configurations have been done on the server as well.

My download controller goes like this:

```
public function download(){ 
    
    $state_name=$this->input->post('state');
    $year=$this->input->post('year');
    
    $final_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $state_name);   //set name by name convention
    $filename=$final_name.'_'.$year.'.zip';             // set file name with extension
    $this->load->helper('download');                          // Load download helper
    $file="my_path".$filename;                                //set file path
    if($state_name!= ' '&& $year!=' '){
        
        
        if (!empty($file)){                                  //check if the file exists
            force_download($file,NULL);                       
        }
        else{
            echo "File not found";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "data not recieved in controller";
    }
```

What could be possibly going wrong with this code even when I have included the helper download in the `autoload.php`  and `controller __construct()` function.?

Thankful for any contribution in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `force_download()` in defined in the helper: `download`

So, to use the helper `download`, you need to include it in class contructor.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
```

Why do it is working on localhost and not on server:

Localhost might have included the helper `download` in `autoload.php` or `controller __construct() function`.

Comment: I forgot to mention but the steps you have stated have already done and the problem still remains as it is.

Comment: Please let me know where did you load the helper `download`?

Comment: I have tried it including in both  `autoload.php` and in the `controller_constructor()`, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Please check the syntax in CodeIgniter Manual, there are chances that something is missing.